# Equation of Laser Beam Divergence

Tags: laser

I am doing experiment to calculate size of beam waist using diode laser. I have calculated beam spot size (x where $I=I_{max} /e^2$) at different distance from Laser source. I am thinking to fit the data to equation governing size of Beam Spot as function of distance from Laser source to find size of beam waist.

Comment: So what is the question? The title? Just look up the Gaussian beam and related equations.

Comment: I looked Wikipedia, and I'm not sure weather this equation $w(z)=w_0 \sqrt{1+(\lambda z /\pi w_0^2)^2}$. Where $\lambda$ is wavelength and $z$ is the length from laser source. $w_0$ is beam waist parameter which I want to find.

Comment: Please add the equation you are looking at, and explain your difficulty with it.

Comment: And with the equation $w(z)=w_0 \sqrt{1+(\lambda z/\pi w_0^0)^2}$, with $\lambda = 650*10^{-7}$ and data points (40,0.7309),(60,1.0940),(80,1.1976),(100,1.6912) (x,y x = distance (cm) from laser source and y = Intensity). I am getting a straight line. (Because $\lambda$ is too small).

Comment: Isn't it easier to do everything where $\times 10^{n}$ where $n$ is  ..., -3, 0, 3, ...  ie mm, $\mu$m and nm?  Your wavelength is in nm and your waist is mm and z in m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a laser diode its divergence will be different in x and y direction (assume z is propagation direction) due to face dimensions/diffraction. If there is no lens on it the divergence is quite high due to diffraction for the tiny area of the diode emitting face.  Most diodes have a lens mounted close to the laser chip and this will capture most of the light and make the beam almost straight.  The focal length/point of the lens is placed so that the most divergent direction is focused to almost perfectly parallel but the other dimension will continue to have some small divergence because the divergence origin is slightly different in the diode chip for x and y.